# How to add SSL site seal in drupal?

Tags: ssl

I have got site seal from positive ssl but cant figure out where to insert it. 
Their support option says inset the code in the html body tag. Its very vague for drupal, at least for me to understand because i dont have much knowledge of the drupal internal structure. Can anyone help please?

Comment: Please explain what exactly is that seal. I mean, we don't care what it means, we care if it's a piece of HTML, JavaScript, PHP or what?

Answer (score 2):

You can just insert it in a Block. just goto Structure > Block > Add Block and enable full html input and just copy and pate. Then just assign that block to where you want it to show up.